# Spark Streaming with Kafka ensure loss less processing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-consumer-api

I have a very simple Spark + Kafka application. I'm reading from Kafka and printing in Console. I have 2 lines in below i.e Good-line and Bad-line

Initially I process with good line, and then I switch to bad-line for a while, when I change back to good line I expect to process from where it left off. Surprisingly it starts from latest.

1
2
3
missing
missing
7
8
9

In the below code how can I ensure I read all the messages. I did not find a code or place where I can control the offset. Even if there is a duplicate processing I'm fine .. coz I'll have unique-id in my message

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String brokers = "quickstart:9092";
    String topics = "simple_topic_1";
    String master = "local[*]";

    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
            .builder().appName(SimpleKafkaProcessor.class.getName())
            .master(master).getOrCreate();
    SQLContext sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext();
    SparkContext context = sparkSession.sparkContext();
    context.setLogLevel("ERROR");

    Dataset<Row> rawDataSet = sparkSession.readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
            //.option("enable.auto.commit", "false")
            .option("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
            .option("group.id", "safe_message_landing_app_2")
            .option("subscribe", topics).load();
    rawDataSet.printSchema();
    rawDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("basicView");

    // Good-Line
    sqlContext.sql("select string(Value) as StrValue from basicView").writeStream()
    // Bad-Line
    //sqlContext.sql("select fieldNotFound as StrValue from basicView").writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "cp/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .trigger(ProcessingTime.create("15 seconds"))
            .start()
            .awaitTermination();

}
```

Comment: can you explain why you are adding and removing bad line manually? are you trying to process all the data once with bad line and once with good line?

Comment: to create error scenario for testing .. if the stream job is running ... it might fail .. may be for network error or no space in downstream .. so when we fix the error and resume .. it should start from where it left off